# How do I solve a problem that involves finding the derivative of of x respect to y?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

I have done problems where I have to find the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$, but not the other way around. Do I do the problem just like the other problems? I'm not sure where to start.

> Let $y=x^7+2x-5$. Calculate $\dfrac{dx}{dy}\bigg\vert_{y=-2}$ the derivative of $x$ with respect to $y$ when $y=-2$.

Comment: Try implicit differentiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Take the derivative of your equation with respect to $y$, you get
$$
1 = 7x^6 \frac{dx}{dy} + 2 \frac{dx}{dy},
$$
can you complete this now?

This is called *implicit differentiation*.

Comment: Oh, I see thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

Note that at $y=-2$ we have $x=1$

$$y=x^7+2x-5$$

$$ 1= 7x^6 x' +2x'$$

$$ x'(2+7x^6)=1$$

$$x'(9)=1 \implies x'=1/9$$

Comment: It would be nice if the OP had to do at least *something* instead of just copying your solution as their homework assignment...

Comment: actually it turns out that all I needed is the implicit differentiation clue to help me out. I was able to figure out the rest. I was just not able to connect the idea that I had to use implicit differentiation. However, I do appreciate this answer because then I can atleast check my work.

Answer (score 0):

Also recognize that $\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$.  So you could just solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$ and then flip it.  Note that this does not work for higher-order derivatives for reasons stated [here](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3459227).